# How to get a DataRow out the current row of a DataReader?

Tags: c#, datarow, datareader

Ok, I would like to extract a `DataRow` out a `DataReader`. I have been looking around for quite some time and it doesn't look like there is a simple way to do this.

I understand a `DataReader` is more a collection of rows but it only read one row at the time.

So my question: is there any way to extract a `DataRow` out the current row of a `DataReader`?

Comment: _"A DataReader is more a collection of rows"_ no, it's more like a view on a single record. A `DataReader` is a forward-only stream to records in the database. You can only look at the current record.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Is there any way to extract a DataRow out the current row of a
>   DataReader ?

No, at least no simple way. Every DataRow belongs to one [Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.table(v=vs.110).aspx). You cannot leave that property empty, you cannot even change the table(without using ImportRow).

But if you need DataRows, why don't you fill a `DataTable` in the first place?

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
using(var con = new SqlConnection("...."))
using(var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ... WHERE...", con))
    da.Fill(table);
// now you have the row(s)
```

If you really need to get the row(s) from the `DataReader` you can use [`reader.GetSchemaTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatablereader.getschematable.aspx) to get all informations about the columns:

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();
    DataTable data = new DataTable();
    foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
    {
        string colName = row.Field<string>("ColumnName");
        Type t = row.Field<Type>("DataType");
        data.Columns.Add(colName, t);
    }
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var newRow = data.Rows.Add();
        foreach (DataColumn col in data.Columns)
        {
            newRow[col.ColumnName] = reader[col.ColumnName];
        }
    }
}
```

But that is not really efficient.

Comment: I will only get one row at time. So this is why I tought a `DataReader` was better than filling a `DataTable` then merging it with other rows in another `DataTable`

Comment: Your edit bring in a nice point of view. How ever it doesn't really look better than filling a `DataTable`with a single row and than merging afterward. I will mark as answer event if it doesn't exactly answer my question.

Answer (score 4):

You're probably asking because you have `DataReader` code that looks something like this:

```
static void ViaDataReader(IDataReader rdr)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-27} {1,-46} {2,-25} {3}", rdr[0], rdr[1], rdr[2], rdr[3]);
}

/// ...

ViaDataReader(DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().CreateDataReader());
```

But as Tim pointed out, if you *know in advance* that you're going to want the `DataRow` at each iteration, you should use `DataTable` instead, and then just iterate on its `Rows` property (following output is identical to above):

```
static void ViaDataTable(IDataReader rdr)
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Load(rdr);
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-27} {1,-46} {2,-25} {3}", row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3]);
}

/// ...

ViaDataTable(DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses().CreateDataReader());
```

If you absolutely must continue using the `DataReader` for some reason, I suppose you could add a loop index integer to that first example, and then grab each row from the (fully-pre-loaded `DataTable`) on each iteration. But since the `DataTable` is richer all-around, there's really no reason not to abandon the `DataReader` after doing the `DataTable.Load()`.

Comment: I'm not so quick to suggest using DataTable. DataReader has a huge advantage over DataTable/DataRow, in that the latter hold the entire result in memory, while the former only holds one row.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would throw my two cents in.

First, the reason the for using data reader in my case is I am processing millions of rows.

My thought on how to do it is;

```
While objDataReader.Read()
    Dim currentRow As DataRow
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Rows.Add(objDataReader)
    currentRow = dt.Rows(0)

    'Do processing...'
     dt = Nothing
     dt.Dispose()
End While
```

I have just added this code to my program. Hopefully it works.