# getting System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.Int32,System.String]] instead of string

Tags: c#, sql-server, botframework, keyvaluepair

I am working on a **MS Bot Framework project** where I am retrieving the value from a key-value pair from database in C#. Previously I had this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
{
     new KeyValuePair<int, string>(obj,_Obj.Questions)
};

Dictionary<int, string> d = new Dictionary<int, string>
{
  { 1, "Welcome, How are you?" },
  { 2, "Tell me something about yourself."},
  { 3, "How much experience do you have?"},
};
```

My goal was to bring the Values such as "Welcome, How are you?", "Tell me something about yourself", etc from database. In order to achieve that I did this:

**Edit:**

**Questions.cs**

```
public static string GetChats(int Id)
{


   using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_FetchData", con))
   {
   var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

   DataTable dt = new DataTable();
   cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);

   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   da.Fill(dt);

   con.Open();

   SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   if (reader.HasRows)
   {
      foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
      {
        string queMsg = row["Description"]?.ToString();
        list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Id, queMsg));
      }
    }

 // class property

 public string WelcomeStmt = GetChats(1).ToString();
```

And the value from above function is getting in this method:

**MyDialog.cs** // this is the dialog for the Bot

```
private static async Task<DialogTurnResult> **NameStepAsync**(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

  return await stepContext.PromptAsync(nameof(TextPrompt), new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text(questions.AskName) }, cancellationToken);
}
```

I am passing the Id value as 1 in **GetChats(Id)** method. So based on that, I should get the corresponding Value.

In the **NameStepAsync** method, I am receiving an unusual parent class I guess instead of actual string that I am expecting.:

> System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.Int32,System.String]].

Does anybody know why this is happening?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get a DataRow out the current row of a DataReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18511700/how-to-get-a-datarow-out-the-current-row-of-a-datareader)

Comment: @Jawad, Thanks that somewhat helped. I used dt.Rows in foreach loop. However, in debug mode I am getting the above parent class instead of actual string.

Comment: It doesn't seem like that code that you've put in the question shows us where the string `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair2[System.Int32,System.String]]` is coming from. It appears that you're effectively doing a `.ToString()` on the `list` instance. But I can't see that in the code. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @Enigmativity please see my updated question.

Comment: @RohanRao - You still haven't provided a [mcve] of your code. As one example, the end of the `GetChats` method is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you're describing is the default behavior of the [`Object.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.8) method, which is to return the fully qualified name of the type of the object. Since `List<T>` does not override `ToString`, you are seeing the output you've described.

It can be reproduced by:

```
Console.WriteLine(list.ToString());   // Or just: Console.WriteLine(list);
```

[image]

If the intent is to output the `Value` property of each `KeyValuePair` in the list, we need to first select that property from each item in the list. For example:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>()
{
    new KeyValuePair<int, string> (1, "Welcome, How are you?" ),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string> (2, "Tell me something about yourself."),
    new KeyValuePair<int, string> (3, "How much experience do you have?"),
};

list.ForEach(kvp => Console.WriteLine(kvp.Value));
```

[image]

I realize this answer ignores a great portion of the code you provided, but it doesn't appear to me that the code you've shown is what's causing the output you described. Hopefully this helps some. :)

Comment: Thank you sir :) Please see my updated question i have provided more details.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question properly but you can try below code or share some more info

```
int idn=0;
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    string queMsg = row["Description"].ToString();
    list.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(idn, queMsg));
    idn=idn+1;
}
```